# JavaScript forEach. String to Date

Tags: javascript, foreach

Есть массив **scheduleDates**:

```
0:"24.04.2016, 11:53"
1:"12.04.2016, 10:07"
2:"13.04.2016, 9:45"
```

Мне нужно сделать из элементов типа **String** элементы типа **Date** в этом же массиве.

Я пытался:

```
scheduleDates.forEach(function (date) {
    var currDate = date.split(', ')[0];
    var currTime = date.split(', ')[1];
    var hours = currTime.split(':')[0];
    var minutes = currTime.split(':')[1];
    var year = currDate.split('.')[2];
    var month = currDate.split('.')[1];
    var day = currDate.split('.')[0];
    var newDate = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
    date = newDate;
});
```

Не сработало.

Answer (score 1):

В не можете *заменить* элемент таким образом, но, вы можете используя [функцию `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) получить новый массив и сохранить его в старой переменной.

```js
var scheduleDates = ["24.04.2016, 11:53", "12.04.2016, 10:07", "13.04.2016, 9:45"]

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(scheduleDates)+'</pre>');

scheduleDates = scheduleDates.map(function(date) {
  var currDate = date.split(', ')[0];
  var currTime = date.split(', ')[1];
  var hours = currTime.split(':')[0];
  var minutes = currTime.split(':')[1];
  var year = currDate.split('.')[2];
  var month = currDate.split('.')[1];
  var day = currDate.split('.')[0];
  return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
});

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(scheduleDates)+'</pre>');
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38855/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-javascript-foreach-string-to-date).

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то вам всего лишь нужно поменять первое число со вторым местами, т.к. различается форматирование даты у русских и зарубежных коллег

```js
var test = ["24.04.2016, 11:53", "12.04.2016, 10:07", "13.04.2016, 9:45"];

test.forEach(function (date) {
    var splitted = date.split('.');
    date = new Date(splitted[1]+'/'+splitted[0]+'/'+splitted[2]); 
  
    alert(date);
    console.log(date);
});
```

Для замены старого значения на новое в том же массиве можно воспользоваться `map`

```js
var test = ["24.04.2016, 11:53", "12.04.2016, 10:07", "13.04.2016, 9:45"];


test = test.map(function(date) {
  var splitted = date.split('.');    

  return new Date(splitted[1]+'/'+splitted[0]+'/'+splitted[2]); 
});

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(test)+'</pre>');
```

Comment: В Chrome все работает, а в Explorer пишет Invalid Date

Comment: @o_ndvtsk, попробуйте заменить 5-ю строку на `date = new Date(splitted[1]+'/'+splitted[0]+'/'+splitted[2]);`

Comment: Опять: Invalid date  в IE, в Chrome работает.

Comment: @o_ndvtsk со слешами даже в IE9 работает......скорее всего проблема в ваших данных...значит они не в таком формате, который вы предоставили

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, chrome слишком "вольно" парсит строки в даты. если предлагаете разбить строку на отдельные элементы ( год, месяц и пр ), то лучше отдельно и передавать: `new Date(year, month, date[, hours, minutes, seconds, ms] )
`